# Dependent types in OCaml

Tags: types, ocaml

There's a lot of information about dependent types in Haskell and Scala. For OCaml, not so much. Is anyone skilled enough to provide a coding example on how to achieve this in OCaml (if it's possible at all)? There is of course (the abandoned) [Dependent ML](http://www.cs.bu.edu/~hwxi/DML/DML.html), but it seems not possible to incorporate such stuff in "regular" OCaml code.

Basically, what I want to do is to remove code like `assert(n > 0)` and check it at compile time.

**EDIT**

As a side note, it's worth mentioning the OCaml [Hybrid Contract Checking](http://gallium.inria.fr/~naxu/research/hcc.html) branch, that could fill some of the needs of a dependent type system. Instead of `assert(n > 0)` you would then write a contract:

```
contract f = {x : x > 0} -> int
let f x = x + 1
let dummy_variable = f (-1) (* Won't compile *)
```

**Edit 2**: For anyone reading this, I think F* is an interesting ML-like language with dependent types.

Comment: May I ask where is this "lot of information about dependent types in Haskell and Scala"? Despite having a reasonable overview of the Haskell community, I don't know what you are referring to. (I would definitely consider the UPenn work on [Dependently-Typed Haskell](http://www.cis.upenn.edu/~sweirich/) as relevant, but that's extremely researchy rather than practical, and maybe not "a lot" in volume). I have no idea what you're thinking of for Scala -- except maybe the relation to path-dependent types?

Comment: Ehm, on stackoverflow, I was thinking. Maybe I was fooled by Scalas path-dependent types.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

A reference link is Oleg's [lightweight static guarantees](https://okmij.org/ftp/Computation/lightweight-static-guarantees.html) pages, with examples (in OCaml or that you can translate to OCaml) of dependent-like techniques used in ML languages. His paper on [Lighweight static capabilities (PDF)](https://homes.luddy.indiana.edu/ccshan/capability/lightweight-static-capabilities.pdf) with Chung-chieh Shan in 2007 is especially relevant.

Edit: Since version 4.00 (released after the document above was written), OCaml has GADTs, which allow to streamline a few techniques for refined static information (previously relying on phantom type techniques), in particular the "singleton types" pattern demonstrated in [Omega](http://code.google.com/p/omega/). It has been shown that they're not essential to get strong typeful programming, but they may still be used by a variety of examples found in the wild.